# How to access a dynamically created DOM element in ComponentDidMount lifecycle method in React?

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-lifecycle

In my react app , I am creating a canvas element dynamically.
Now, I want to access that DOM element from ComponentDidMount lifecycle method, however, I am not able to do that.
Below is my code :
https://codesandbox.io/s/drawing-on-canvas-by-mouse-events-forked-ezrdgd

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: @noodlejs Could you pls answer this?

Comment: @Will Jenkins could you pls answer my question?